# Call Ajax when click button submit with validationform.io

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I use Plugin Jquery : "ValidationForm" in site : http://formvalidation.io/. When i click button Submit, i call Ajax to server. In here Plugin ValidationForm don't validate fields,but call Ajax. My code :

Html:

```
<button type="submit" class"btn btn-success" id="#button"></button>
```

ValidationForm code:

```
$('#form').bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'Not Valid',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                PhoneNumber: {
                    message: 'Not Null',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Not Null'
                        },
                        stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                            max: 100,
                            message: '2->100 characters'
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        ;
```

jQuery: event click button submit

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
        //....
       })
});
```

I want to check validation form before submit form with Ajax.

Comment: some js code would help to see how you did it :)

Comment: check this example http://formvalidation.io/examples/ajax-submit/

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post relevant code here so that we can have a look at it. also if possible try to replicate the issue on jsfiddle.http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please use the correct tags for your issue.  The jQuery Validate plugin is not the Bootstrap Validator plugin.  Edited. Thanks.